# Sending Message iPhone to Any iPhone over Wi-fi ( Data) across world

Tags: iphone, wifi, message

I want to develop an application which sends a Message from iPhone to other iPhone over the internet, I want to receive the Message from other iPhone even if my iPhone is running in the background.
I have seen the WiTap application, but socket will get disconnect when application is closed or if there is screen lock.

So is that possible to develop the application so that I can receive the message even if my app running in the background forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my little Knowledge, **You can't do** it through WiFi.

When a screen lock happened, device will automatically OFF the wifi connection for increasing battery life.Thats why socket connection getting disconnected.

In iOS, apps can’t do a lot in the background. Apps are only allowed to do limited set of activities so battery life is conserved.

But what if something interesting happens and you wish to let the user know about this, even if they’re not currently using your app.

For example, maybe the user received a new chat. Since the app isn’t currently running, it cannot check for these events.

Luckily, Apple has provided a solution to this. Instead of your app continuously checking for events or doing work in the background, you can write a server-side component to do this instead.

You can do it using Apple **Push Notification Service**.

It uses push technology through a constantly open IP connection to forward notifications from the servers of third party applications to the Apple devices; such notifications may include badges, sounds or custom text alerts. In iOS 5, Notification Center enhanced the user experience of push and local notifications.

More details are [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

[image]

**Note:** details and screen shots are taken from **[raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com)** website/blog.